# revalidate form and checking each input after editing

Tags: php

I created the fields that has validation process like required fields, numbers only and valid email.

it displays the errors simultaneously after submit but upon changing only one of the fields, it accepts and does not revalidate the other.

example 
name = Error : required field 
telephone = Error : numbers only 
email = Error : not a valid email

after i corrected only the email , it accepts and proceed on submitting without rechecking the others.
please see my code . thanks in advance

```
<?php
include("conn/db.php");
function renderForm($name ='',  $tel = '', $email ='', $error='',  $error2='', $error3='')
{
?>
<html >
<head> <title>Form</title></head>
<body>

<?php
if ($error != '') {
echo $error
}
if ($error2 != '') {
echo $error2;
}  
if ($error3 != '') {
echo  $error3;
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">

Name : <input type = "text" class = "form-control" name = "name_text"  value="<?php echo $name; ?>">  <br/>
Tel :<input type = "text" class = "form-control" name = "tel_text"  value="<?php echo $tel; ?>"> <br/>
Email :<input type ="text" class = "form-control " name = "email_text" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" > <br/>

<input name= "submit" type="submit" value="Update" class = "btn btn-primary" >

</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php 
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

$name = $_POST['name_text'];
$tel = $_POST['tel_text'];
$email = $_POST['email_text'];

    if ($name== '' ){
        $error = 'ERR: required field';
        }
    if(!is_numeric($telephone)){
        $error2 = 'ERR: numbers only';
        }
    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $error3 = 'ERR: Email not valid';
        }
    else
    {
    ***WILL PROCESS THE SQL QUERY ***
    header("Location: main.php");
    }

    renderForm($name, $tel , $email ,$error, $error2, $error3);
}
else{
renderForm();
}

$con->close();
?>
```

Comment: Consider `type="email"` also could you please explain further what the issue is, the question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
include("conn/db.php");
function renderForm($name ='',  $tel = '', $email ='', $error='',  $error2='', $error3='')
{
?>
<html >
<head> <title>Form</title></head>
<body>

<?php
if ($error != '') {
echo $error
}
if ($error2 != '') {
echo $error2;
}  
if ($error3 != '') {
echo  $error3;
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">

Name : <input type = "text" class = "form-control" name = "name_text"  value="<?php echo $name; ?>">  <br/>
Tel :<input type = "text" class = "form-control" name = "tel_text"  value="<?php echo $tel; ?>"> <br/>
Email :<input type ="text" class = "form-control " name = "email_text" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" > <br/>

<input name= "submit" type="submit" value="Update" class = "btn btn-primary" >

</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php 
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

$name = $_POST['name_text'];
$tel = $_POST['tel_text'];
$email = $_POST['email_text'];
$is_valid = true;
    if ($name== '' ){
        $error = 'ERR: required field';
        $is_valid = false;
    }
    if(!is_numeric($telephone)){
        $error2 = 'ERR: numbers only';
        $is_valid = false;
        }
    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $error3 = 'ERR: Email not valid';
        $is_valid = false;
        }

    if($is_valid) {
    ***WILL PROCESS THE SQL QUERY ***
    header("Location: main.php");
    }

    renderForm($name, $tel , $email ,$error, $error2, $error3);
}
else{
renderForm();
}

$con->close();
?>
```

Its just a small mistake:

```
if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $error3 = 'ERR: Email not valid';
} else {
    ***WILL PROCESS THE SQL QUERY ***
    header("Location: main.php");
}
```

You only checked the email and if it is corecct it was proceding. It did not include the other 2 checks for name and number.

I added a small variable to check if all 3 are correct.